# Why my SASS project is disregarding media breakpoints?

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, sass

I used to use CSS for a React project, but for the implementation of a "dark mode" functionality I decided to move to SASS.

I also use bootstrap so I organize my files according to the [documentation](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction/#sass).

```
/* App.scss */

@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss";
@import './styles/_themes';
@import './styles/_fonts';


h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
  font-family: $font-family-secondary;
  @include themed() {
    color: t($title-color)
  }
} 

p {
  font-family: $font-family-primary;

  @include themed() {
    color: t($text-color)
  }
}

hr, .nav-tabs {
  @include themed() {
    border-color: t($text-secondary-color)
  }
}

.base {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  
  @include themed() {
    background-color: t($background-color)
  }
}

.main {
  width: 750px;

  @include themed() {
    background-color: t($background-color)
  }
}
```

First, I thought it was a bootstrap problem, but the breakpoints are also being disregarding in my own files.

```
/* Footer.scss */

@media (max-width: 767px){
    #footer h5 {
        padding-left: 0;
        border-left: transparent;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
   }
}
```

I made a minimal reproducible example and posted it to codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/immutable-fire-qu9oe

Please, try to decrease the screen size and check the media breakpoints being disregarded.

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much!

EDIT:

Thanks to [robertp's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66888323/why-my-sass-project-is-disregarding-media-breakpoints/66889005#66889005) I could fix my custom media breakpoints.

But how can I fix bootstrap ones?

For example, in my `navbar` I have a media breakpoint for a bootstrap class:

```
/* Navbar.scss */

@media (max-width: 571px) {
  .collapsing {
    @include themed() {
      position: absolute !important;
      z-index: 3;
      width: 100%;
      top: 75px;
    }
  }

  .collapse.show {
    @include themed() {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      z-index: 3;
      width: 100%;
      top: 75px;
    }
  }

  .navbar.open {
    @include themed() {
      transform: translate(0, 0)
    }
  }

  .overlay.open {
    @include themed() {
      height: 100%;
      opacity: 1;
    }
  }

}
```

But it didn't work. Also, how I could fix all bootstrap grid system classes?

EDIT 2:

**The problem was the import order. If I put the bootstrap import at the end of the file everythings works as expected!**

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be due to specificity in the theme. Your footer H5 element is styled as per the theme, so you need to override the themed version of it.

**Screenshot of the themed styling overriding your mediaquery based styling:**

[image: See screenshot of what rendered in browser]

#### This should work:

```
@media (max-width: 767px){
  #footer h5 {
    @include themed() {
      padding-left: 0;
      border-left: transparent;
      padding-bottom: 0px;
      margin-bottom: 10px;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! This indeed fix my custom media breakpoints, but how I can fix the bootstrap ones?

Comment: Looking at your demo, it is not clear what you're trying to fix in Bootstrap. I can't see any more breakpoints in your code, and the theming seems to work for me (site colours change when I hit the sun Icon in the TR). Can you specify what Bootstrap specific issues you're having, and where the relevant code is?

Comment: If you check the sandbox you can see that the columns aren't resizing when we decrease the screen width. For larger devices, there are expected to be two columns per row and for smaller devices, one. If you decrease the screen width you will always see two colums per row. The relevant code probably is related to custom bootstrap's classes, but you can see the react implementation on the `Home.js` file (src/componentes/common in the sandbox).

Comment: I edited the question to provide more detail. Thanks again!

Comment: Please see my updated answer with information on how to resize the columns in your grid on different breakpoints.

Comment: I know how to resize the columns, the problem is that the bootstrap classes are not being applied due to some SASS problem!